# Android - How can I open a persistent HTTP connection that receives chunked responses?

Tags: android, http, chunked

I'm trying to establish a persistent HTTP connection to an API endpoint that publishes chunked JSON responses as new events occur. I would like to provide a callback that is called each time the server sends a new chunk of data, and keep the connection open indefinitely. As far as I can tell, neither `HttpClient` nor `HttpUrlConnection` provide this functionality.

Is there a way to accomplish this without using a TCP socket?

Comment: any solutions for this? I am trying to do same.

Comment: @akbas I've posted a solution using `HttpClient`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27430319/3875216

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a delimeter such as `\n\n` to separate each json event.  You could remove blank lines from original json before sending.  Calling `setChunkedStreamingMode(0)` allows you to read content as it comes in (rather than after the entire request has been buffered).  Then you can simply go through each line, storing them, until a blank line is reached, then parse the stored lines as JSON.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.length() == 0) {
        processJsonEvent(sBuffer.toString());
        sBuffer.delete(0, sBuffer.length());
    } else {
        sBuffer.append(line);
        sBuffer.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, Android's `HttpURLConnection` doesn't support receiving chunks of data across a persistent HTTP connection; it instead waits for the response to fully complete.

Using `HttpClient`, however, works:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(new URI("https://www.yourStreamingUrlHere.com"));
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    InputStream responseStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

    String line;
    do {
        line = rd.readLine();
        // handle new line of data here
    } while (!line.isEmpty());


    // reaching here means the server closed the connection
} catch (Exception e) {
    // connection attempt failed or connection timed out
}
```

Comment: unfortunately ```HttpClient``` is deprecated in favor of ```HttpURLConnection``` (and it has been removed in Android 6).

Comment: i think youre wrong about HttpURLConnetction, it can receive chunk data by using a SAX Handler